# How to solve this error: "Alert" cannot be used as a jsx component. Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: reactjs

App.tsx

```
import { Alert } from "./Alert";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <Alert heading="Success">Everything is really good!</Alert>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Alert.tsx

```
type Props = {
  type?: string;
  heading: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  closable?: boolean;
  onClose?: () => void;
};

export function Alert({
  type = "information",
  heading,
  children,
  closable,
  onClose,
}: Props) {}
```

I tried to update all packages nothing helps.
Error: ""Alert" cannot be used as a jsx component. Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element"

Answer (score 1):

You didn't return any JSX Element there so it caused the issue.

Try this in Alert.tsx:

```
type Props = {
  type?: string;
  heading: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  closable?: boolean;
  onClose?: () => void;
};

export function Alert({
  type = "information",
  heading,
  children,
  closable,
  onClose
}: Props) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much. I am just learning and trying to understand all of that. Thank u!